# Jaxb unmarshalling (xml to object)and marshalling (object to xml) , the xmls are slighly different

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Using JAXB, I tried unmarshalling (xml to object)and marshalling (object to xml). I have noticed that there is slight difference in xml formatting, though I feel technically both are same.

> Original xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Sites>
<Site id="101" name="NY-01" location="New York" xmlns="http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd">
    <Hosts>
        <Host id="1001">
           <Host_Name>srv001001</Host_Name>
           <IP_address>10.1.2.3</IP_address>
           <OS>Windows</OS>
           <Load_avg_1min>1.3</Load_avg_1min>
           <Load_avg_5min>2.5</Load_avg_5min>
           <Load_avg_15min>1.2</Load_avg_15min>
        </Host>

    </Hosts>
</Site>
</Sites>
```

> After marshalling the object to xml, the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Sites xmlns:ns2="http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd">
    <ns2:Site location="New York" name="NY-01" id="101">
        <ns2:Hosts>
            <ns2:Host id="1001">
                <ns2:Host_Name>srv001001</ns2:Host_Name>
                <ns2:IP_address>10.1.2.3</ns2:IP_address>
                <ns2:OS>Windows</ns2:OS>
                <ns2:Load_avg_1min>1.3</ns2:Load_avg_1min>
                <ns2:Load_avg_5min>2.5</ns2:Load_avg_5min>
                <ns2:Load_avg_15min>1.2</ns2:Load_avg_15min>
            </ns2:Host>

</Sites>
```

How do i make both the input source xml and final output the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057733/how-to-get-jaxb-output-to-have-namespace-included-with-the-child-node-with-no-pr
although that has no answer yet either

Answer (score 0):

The document XML documents have equivalent namespace qualification.

### When JAXB Declares a Default Namepsace

When you specify the following package level `@XmlSchema` annotation then a JAXB implementation will typically leverage a default namespace:

```java
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd"",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

### Why JAXB is not Using a Default Namespace Here

In your XML document not all of your XML elements are namespace qualified (`Site` is, but `Sites` is not) so JAXB saves no prefix to mean no namespace instead of the default namespace.

```xml
<Sites>
    <Site id="101" name="NY-01" location="New York" xmlns="http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd">
```